# autokey shift and right mouse click

Tags: python, linux, autohotkey, manjaro, autokey

I am trying to make a script in linux that uses **<kbd>Shift</kbd> + right click** in eight desired positions.

I already tried to emulate autohotkey in linux but it doesn't work correctly.

This is an example of autohotkey code "+" means "Shift" on autohotkey

```
Send +{Click 842, 464, right}  
Send +{Click 853, 530, right}
Send +{Click 783, 531, right}
Send +{Click 713, 529, right} 
Send +{Click 715, 461, right}
Send +{Click 714, 395, right}
Send +{Click 785, 394, right}
Send +{Click 852, 395, right}
MouseMove, StartX, StartY
```

Comment: I doubt AHK can work well on Linux, because it depends on a lot of Windows-specific syscalls and APIs.

Comment: yes thats why i want to convert this script to autokey

Comment: i have tried this but i think is very fast if is possible to add like wait ms:10
```
# Enter script code
keyboard.press_key("<shift>")
mouse.click_absolute(882, 504, 3)
keyboard.release_key("<shift>")```

Comment: It is possible to split up and down instructions. You can for example do 
```Send, {Shift down}{Click down, right}```
put a delay (```Sleep, X```) and then
```Send, {Click up, right}{Shift up}```.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent Autokey script would be something like this:

```
system.exec_command("xte 'mousemove 842 464' 'mouseclick 3'", False)
system.exec_command("xte 'mousemove 853 530' 'mouseclick 3'", False)
...
```

where `xte` must be installed.

See this example: https://github.com/autokey/autokey/wiki/Scripting#gnome-screenshot

Comment: AutoKey has some mouse event functionality once you get a newer version than 0.90.4, but calling out to external programs as this answer does will usually work better. It's an area of the program which needs enhancement.